# Bootstrap collapse - how to add additional click behavior that depends on the state of collapse or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a button that controls the expansion/collapse of a collapsible div.  But I want to add additional functionality on click that depends on whether the div is expanding or collapsing.  I wrote this code:

```
    buttonElement.click(function() {
      if ($(this).hasClass("collapsed")) {
        // do the thing I want to do when expanding
      } else {
        // do the thing I want to do when collapsing
      }
    })
```

This works, but I'm wondering if it's robust.  It assumes that my click function runs before the data-toggle changes the class, and I'm not sure if it's appropriate to assume this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best thing you can do is read [Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-events) :)

Your solution is not the best, because if you double click on your button fast enough it will execute code inside your if statement AND in else statement (with collapsing only once)

> This event fires immediately when the show instance method is called.

```
$('#myCollapsible').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
  // do something…
});
```

> This event is fired when a collapse element has been made visible to
>   the user (will wait for CSS transitions to complete).

```
$('#myCollapsible').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
  // do something…
});
```

> This event is fired immediately when the hide method has been called.

```
$('#myCollapsible').on('hide.bs.collapse', function () {
  // do something…
});
```

> This event is fired when a collapse element has been hidden from the
>   user (will wait for CSS transitions to complete).

```
$('#myCollapsible').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
  // do something…
});
```

Example:

```
$('[data-toggle="collapse"]').click(function() {
  var collapsibleDiv = $(this).closest('.panel').find('.panel-collapse');
  collapsibleDiv.on('show.bs.collapse', function() {
    $('body').css('background', '#1abc9c');
  });
  collapsibleDiv.on('shown.bs.collapse', function() {
    $('body').css('background', '#e74c3c');
  });
  collapsibleDiv.on('hide.bs.collapse', function() {
    $('body').css('background', '#3498db');
  });
  collapsibleDiv.on('hidden.bs.collapse', function() {
    $('body').css('background', '#7f8c8d');
  });
});
```

### [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/makshh/pen/vKKdPp?editors=1010)

Comment: Is `$('#myCollapsible')` here the collapsible div?  I want the functionality to be attached to the button that toggles the collapsed state of the div, rather than the div.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're doing here.  Every time the button is clicked, I'm going to add the "on" behaviors to the relevant div?  Question -- is there something wrong with the approach I used?  And if so can you explain what it is?  Because it works and it seems much simpler than what you are doing here.

Comment: Yes, everytime the button is clicked, `on` events works on related div to this button. Try to double click fast enough with your approach and you will see the problem.

Comment: Thanks.  I start with the div collapsed, but for some reason it doesn't seem to trigger show.bs.collapse the first time it is expanded, only subsequent times.

Comment: Hmm strange, can you show your code? JSFiddle or Codepen?

Comment: I figured out what my problem was - I am generating the collapsible div the first time the button is clicked, so that time, since there isn't yet a collapsible div to trigger .on() anything, nothing happens obviously.  I fixed it by doing the right thing explicitly the first time, before creating the collapsible div and hooking it up.

Comment: I still don't understand why you are calling collapsibleDiv.on() inside the click() function though.  It seems like that on() behavior is getting added repeatedly instead of needing to add it only once.

Comment: That's because I don't really understand what you exactly want to achieve. You said, "I want the functionality to be attached to the button that toggles the collapsed state of the div, rather than the div.". You can delete `click()` function and it will work too.

Comment: suppose there are multiple ways of triggering the collapse/show, but I only want to trigger the additional action on a particular button press, but have its behavior depend on the collapsed or not state of the collapsible div.

Comment: So you can use the example I provided in the Codepen (one that applies to the one element - `#collapseFour` in this case). If your button that triggers particular collapsible div is outside the `panel-group` you can add another class to `panel-collapse` to identify this collapsible div in JS code.

Comment: If you edit your question to say why my solution is no good, I will go ahead and accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is the best for simple tasks that occur more frequently.

In addition to the `collapsed` class, you can use **[a special attribute](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#callout-collapse-accessibility)**:

> Be sure to add `aria-expanded` to the control element. <...> The plugin will automatically toggle this attribute based on whether or not the collapsible element has been opened or closed.

Both of these methods indicate the status of the toggle button, but not the state of the object which is operated by the button. When an object is controlled by a few buttons, you need to look for other signs.

You can use **[three other classes](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-usage)** to check the status of the object itself:

> The collapse plugin utilizes a few classes to handle the heavy lifting:
>   
> `.collapse` hides the content
>   
> `.collapse.in` shows the content
>   
>  `.collapsing` is added when the transition starts, and removed when it finishes