# Is it possible to combine bootstrap collapse and javascript onclick event?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

So I'm trying to dynamically populate a bootstrap (5) nav bar with data from mysql using Flask. To populate the Div related to the nav bar item, I want to use bootstrap collapse, but the data in the Div is dependent on the selected nav bar item. What this means is that when the link in the navbar is clicked, there should be two actions initiated: get the specific data from the mysql database using Flask and collapse the div where the data will be showed. This is my code, but it doesn't work:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        {% for info in data[0] %}
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="collapse" onclick="location.href='{{url_for('infoview', selected=info[0])}}'" 
href="#collapseInfo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseInfo">{{info[0]}}</a>
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="collapseInfo">
  ...
</div>
```

Is is possible to combine an onclick event with bootstrap collapse and if so, how?

Comment: Why not use the built in bootstrap collapse (collapse/expand) events? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37846459/bootstrap-collapse-how-to-add-additional-click-behavior-that-depends-on-the-st

Comment: So I should be pointing the href to #collapseInfo and then use `$('#collapseInfo').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {` to fetch the data from the flask endpoint? How would I fetch this data dynamically (dependent on the {{info}} item clicked)?